# Move data entry to the next field when one is full - JS tabulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my script..

User needs to input data to a div and when one div is full (4 characters) the script should automatically move to the next field.

When working with inputs this works very good:
http://jsfiddle.net/4m5fg/452/

But the problem is I want to enter data via virtual keyboard and I can't use focus any more.. So I have tried to input data to class specific div and once the div is full remove the class and add the class to the next div, but it doesn't work..

```
var a = document.getElementById("a"),
    b = document.getElementById("b"),
    c = document.getElementById("c");
var $write = $(".active");

$('#keyboard').click(function() {
    var checka = $('#a').html().length;
    var checkb = $('#b').html().length;

    if (checka === 4) {
        a.removeClass("active");
        b.addClass("active");
    } else if (checkb === 4) {
        b.removeClass("active");
        c.addClass("active");
    }

    var $this = $(this),
        character = $this.html();
    $(".active").html($write.html() + character);
});

$('.delete').click(function() {
    var html = $write.html();
    $write.html(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
    return false;
});
```

Here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/4m5fg/456/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems in your code.

1. To use `.removeClass` and `.addClass` functions you need a jQuery object but not a Node element.
2. Once you entered 4 `A` to the first div the `checka` is still `4` so you need to check if `checkb == 0`.
3. You need to get the current `.active` each time but not just in page load. So you need put `var $write = $(".active");` inside the `click` event.

```js
var a = $("#a"),
    b = $("#b"),
    c = $("#c"),
    $write;

$('#keyboard').click(function(){
  var checka = $('#a').html().length;
  var checkb = $('#b').html().length;

  if (checka === 4 && checkb === 0) {
    a.removeClass("active");
    b.addClass("active");
  }
  else if (checkb === 4) {
    b.removeClass("active");
    c.addClass("active");
  }

  $write = $(".active");

  var $this = $(this),
      character = $this.html();

  $(".active").html($write.html() + character);
});

$('.delete').click(function() {
  var html = $write.html();
  $write.html(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
  
  if ($write.html().length == 0) {
      $write = $write.prev();
  }
  
  return false;
});
```

```css
.block {
  background: #fff; 
  color: red; 
  border: 0; 
  width: 45px; 
  height: 20px; 
  padding: 10px; 
  float: left; 
  margin: 5px;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" class="block active" ></div>
<div id="b" class="block active2"  ></div>
<div id="c" class="block" ></div>

<div id="keyboard">A</div>
<span class="delete">DEL</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjsv8dt5/)

```
$(".keyboard").on("click", function() {

  $(".block").removeClass("active").filter(function() {
    return this.innerText.length < 4;
  }).first().addClass("active").append(this.innerText);

});

$(".delete").on("click", function() {

  var inputs = $(".block").removeClass("active").filter(function() {
    return this.innerText.length > 0;
  }).last().addClass("active").html(function() {
    return this.innerText.substr(0, this.innerText.length - 1);
  });

});
```

If you are building a virtual keyboard I suggest to use `class` instead of `id`. 
This way every `.keyboard` will turn into a `key` and can easily be selected into the inputs.

Using `this.innerText.length` you can check if the input is complete.. and also you can change the `4` with some attribute that you already have and turn your code more dynamic.

To change the 'active class' you can just find all `.blocks` and remove this class.. after you find the current block just append it again.

Finally, the `DEL Key` find the last block with some text and remove the last char.

EDIT: [New example with active class](http://jsfiddle.net/hjsv8dt5/)

Answer (score 1):

You have few errors here is fixed code:

```
var a = $("#a"),
    b = $("#b"),
    c = $("#c");
    var $write = $(".active");

$('#keyboard').click(function(){

  var checka = $('#a').html().length;
  var checkb = $('#b').html().length;

  if (checka === 4) {
    a.removeClass("active");
    b.addClass("active");
    $write = b;
  }
  if (checkb === 4) {
    b.removeClass("active");
    c.addClass("active");
    $write = c;
  }

  var $this = $(this),
      character = $this.html();
  $(".active").html($write.html() + character);


});
$('.delete').click(function() {
    var html = $write.html();
  if (html.length == 0) {
    if ($write.is('#c')) {
        $write.removeClass('active');
        $write = b;
      $write.addClass('active');
    } else if ($write.is('#b')) {
        $write.removeClass('active');
        $write = a;
      $write.addClass('active');
    }
    html = $write.html();
  }
  $write.html(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
  return false;
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4m5fg/458/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<app-step1 class="star-inserted">
  <div c79="" class="form-group mt-2 star-inserted">
      <ng-otp-input c79="" _nghost-gtc-c25="">
        <input id="" type="text" class="otp-input" c25="" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" pattern="\d*" charCodeLimit='[48,57]'>
        <input id="" type="text" class="otp-input" c25="" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" pattern="\d*" charCodeLimit='[48,57]'>
        <input id="" type="text" class="otp-input" c25="" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" pattern="\d*" charCodeLimit='[48,57]'>
        <input id="" type="text" class="otp-input" c25="" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" pattern="\d*" charCodeLimit='[48,57]'>
        <input id="" type="text" class="otp-input" c25="" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" pattern="\d*" charCodeLimit='[48,57]'>
        <input id="" type="text" class="otp-input" c25="" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" pattern="\d*" charCodeLimit='[48,57]'>
      </ng-otp-input>
    </div>
  </div>
</app-step1>
```

And

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("star-inserted")[0];
container.onkeyup = function(e) {
  var target = e.srcElement;
  if (target.value.length >= target.maxLength) {
    var next = target;
    while (next = next.nextElementSibling) {
      if (next == null)
        break;
      if (next.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
        next.focus();
        next.setSelectionRange(0, next.value.length);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
container.onkeypress = function(e) {
  let charCodeLimit = e.target.getAttribute("charCodeLimit");
  if (charCodeLimit) {
    let limit = JSON.parse(charCodeLimit);
    if(limit.length==2){
      return (e.charCode >= limit[0] && e.charCode <= limit[1]) || e.charCode == 0;
    }
  }
}
container.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
    e.target.select();
  }
}
```

**Online Demo**
https://jsfiddle.net/nsvbtkzq/